# How to get the topic using pyspark LDA

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have used LDA for finding the topic
[ref:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda)

> from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA
>   lda = LDA(k=30, seed=123, optimizer="em", maxIter=10, featuresCol="features")
>
> ldamodel = lda.fit(rescaledData)

when i run the below code i find the result with topic, termIndices and termWeights

> ldatopics = ldamodel.describeTopics()

```
+-----+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|topic|termIndices                        |termWeights                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13643518321703474, 0.09550636070102715, 0.0948398694152729, 0.05766480874922468, 0.04482014536392716, 0.04435413761288223, 0.04390248330822808, 0.042949351875241376, 0.039792489008412854, 0.03959557452696915]   |
|1    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13650714786977475, 0.09549302392463813, 0.09473573233391298, 0.05765172919949817, 0.04483412655497465, 0.04437734133645192, 0.043917280973977395, 0.042966507550942196, 0.03978157454461109, 0.039593095881148545] |
|2    |[18, 14, 1, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13628285951099658, 0.0960680469091329, 0.0957882659160997, 0.05753830851677705, 0.04476298485932895, 0.04426297294164529, 0.043901044582340995, 0.04291495373567377, 0.039780501358024425, 0.03946491774918109]    |
|3    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13674345908386384, 0.09541103313663375, 0.09430192089972703, 0.05770255869404108, 0.044821207138198024, 0.04441671155466873, 0.043902024784365994, 0.04294093494951478, 0.03981953622791824, 0.039614320304130965] |
|4    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.1364122091134319, 0.0953545543783122, 0.09429906593265366, 0.05772444907583193, 0.044862863343866806, 0.04442734201228477, 0.04389557512474934, 0.04296443267889805, 0.03982659626276644, 0.03962640467091713]     |
|5    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13670139028438008, 0.09553267874876908, 0.0946605951853061, 0.05768305061621247, 0.04480375989378822, 0.04435320773212808, 0.043914956101645836, 0.0429208816887896, 0.03981783866996495, 0.0395571526370012]      |
|6    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13655841155238757, 0.09554895256001286, 0.0949549658561804, 0.05762248195720487, 0.04480233168639564, 0.04433230827791344, 0.04390710584467472, 0.042930742282966325, 0.039814043132483344, 0.039566695745809]     |
|7    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13663380500078914, 0.09550193655114965, 0.09478283807049456, 0.05766262514700366, 0.04480957336655386, 0.044349558779903736, 0.04392217503495675, 0.04293742117414056, 0.03978830895805316, 0.03953804442817271]   |
|8    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13657941125100242, 0.09553782026082008, 0.09488224957791296, 0.0576562888735838, 0.04478320710416449, 0.044348589637858433, 0.043920567136734125, 0.04291002130418712, 0.03979768943659999, 0.039567161368513126]  |
|9    |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13679375890331896, 0.09550217013809542, 0.09456405056150366, 0.057658739173097585, 0.04482551122651224, 0.0443527568707439, 0.04392317149752475, 0.04290757658934661, 0.03979803663250257, 0.03956130101562635]    |
|10   |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.1363532425412472, 0.09567087909028642, 0.09540557719048867, 0.0576159180949091, 0.044781629751243876, 0.04429913174899199, 0.04391116942509204, 0.042932143462292065, 0.03978668768070522, 0.03951443679027362]    |
|11   |[18, 1, 14, 2, 6, 15, 19, 0, 5, 11]|[0.13652547151289018, 0.09563212101150799, 0.09559109602844051, 0.057554258392101834, 0.044746350635605996, 0.044288429293621624, 0.04393701569930993, 0.04291245197810508, 0.03976607824588965, 0.039502323331991364]|


+---------++--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then i ran the below code for transforming, which gives my whole input data with "topicDistribution", i want to know, how can i map their corresponding topic from above.

> transformed = ldamodel.transform(rescaledData)
>   transformed.show(1000,truncate=False)

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |topicDistribution                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|(20,[0,1,2,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18],[1.104871083111864,2.992600400740947,2.6744520065699304,1.3684833461617696,2.2505718610977468,1.667281425641495,0.4887254650789885,1.6871692149804491,1.2395584596083011,1.1654793679713804,1.1856289804763125,0.8839314023462759,1.3072768360965874,1.8484873888968552])                                                              |[0.033335920691559356,0.03333070077028474,0.033333697225675085,0.03333561564482505,0.03333642468043084,0.033329348877568624,0.033332822489008374,0.0333260618235691,0.0333303226504357,0.03333271017792987,0.03332747782859632,0.03332947925144302,0.03332588375760626,0.03333450406000825,0.03333113684458691,0.03333479529731098,0.03333650038104409,0.03333779171890448,0.033330895429371024,0.03333346818374588,0.03333587374669536,0.03333749064143864,0.033334190553966234,0.03333150654339392,0.03333448663832666,0.03333989460983954,0.03333245526240933,0.03333885169495637,0.03333318824494455,0.03333650428012542]               |
|(20,[1,3,9,10,11,18],[0.997533466913649,1.2726157969776226,1.4661763952369655,1.6871692149804491,1.2395584596083011,1.2323249259312368])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |[0.03333282248535624,0.033332445609854544,0.033328001364314915,0.03333556680774651,0.03333511480351705,0.03333350870876004,0.03333187395000147,0.03333445718728295,0.03333444971729848,0.03333408945721941,0.033330403594416406,0.03333043254420633,0.03333157466407796,0.033332770049699215,0.033328359180981044,0.03333228442030213,0.03333371386494732,0.03333681533414124,0.0333317544337193,0.0333325923806738,0.03333507835375717,0.0333340926283776,0.033334289011977415,0.03333710235559251,0.033333843031028085,0.03333431818041727,0.03333321848222645,0.03333712581455898,0.03333342489994699,0.033334476683601115]              |
|(20,[0,1,2,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,17,18],[1.104871083111864,2.992600400740947,2.6744520065699304,1.3684833461617696,2.2505718610977468,1.667281425641495,0.4887254650789885,1.6871692149804491,1.2395584596083011,1.1654793679713804,1.1856289804763125,0.8839314023462759,1.3072768360965874,1.8484873888968552])                                                              |[0.03333351262221663,0.03334603652469889,0.03332161942705381,0.03333027102774255,0.03333390930010211,0.03333191764996061,0.033329934469446876,0.033333299309223546,0.033341041908943575,0.0333327792244044,0.0333317683142701,0.03332955596634091,0.033328132222973345,0.033337885062247365,0.03332933802183438,0.033340558825094374,0.03332932381968907,0.033330915221236455,0.03333188695334856,0.033327196223241304,0.0333344223760765,0.03332799716207421,0.033338186672894565,0.033336730538183736,0.03333440038338333,0.033337949318794795,0.033333179017769575,0.03333720003330217,0.0333312634707931,0.033337788932659276]          |
|(20,[7,10,14,15,18],[1.667281425641495,1.6871692149804491,1.1856289804763125,0.8839314023462759,1.2323249259312368])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |[0.03333299162768077,0.03333267864965697,0.03333419860453984,0.0333335178997543,0.03333360724598342,0.03333242559458429,0.03333347136144222,0.03333355459499807,0.03333358147457144,0.03333288221459248,0.033333183195193086,0.03333412789444317,0.033334780263427975,0.033333456529848454,0.033336348770946406,0.03333413810342763,0.03333364116227056,0.03333271328980694,0.033333953427323364,0.03333358082109339,0.03333219641721605,0.03333309878777325,0.03333357447436248,0.03333149527336071,0.03333364840046119,0.03333405705432205,0.03333193039244976,0.033332142999523764,0.0333329476480237,0.033332075826922346]              |
|(20,[7,10,14,15,18],[1.667281425641495,1.6871692149804491,1.1856289804763125,0.8839314023462759,1.2323249259312368])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |[0.033333498405871936,0.033333280285774286,0.03333426144981626,0.033332860785526656,0.033333582231251914,0.03333268142499894,0.0333323342942777,0.033333434542768936,0.03333306424165755,0.0333326212718143,0.03333359821538673,0.03333408970522017,0.03333440903364261,0.033333628480934824,0.033335988240581156,0.03333411840979216,0.03333341827050789,0.033332367335435646,0.033334058739684515,0.03333355988453005,0.033332524988062315,0.03333411721155432,0.033333323503042835,0.03333212784312619,0.0333335375674124,0.03333359055906317,0.033332183680577915,0.033332671344198254,0.03333288800754154,0.03333218004594688]         |
|(20,[2,5,9,16,17,18],[0.8914840021899768,1.3684833461617696,0.4887254650789885,1.63668714555745,2.614553672193175,0.6161624629656184])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |[0.033334335349062126,0.033335078498013884,0.03332587515068904,0.03333663657766274,0.03333680954467168,0.03333423911759284,0.03333228558123402,0.03333307701307248,0.03333230070449398,0.03333357555321742,0.03333013898196302,0.033329558017855816,0.033331357742536066,0.03333281031681836,0.03332620861451679,0.03333164736607878,0.033333411422713344,0.03333811924641809,0.03333032668669555,0.03333155312673253,0.03333601811939769,0.03333261877594549,0.03333490102064452,0.033338814952549214,0.03333297326837463,0.03333518474628696,0.03333659535650031,0.033334882391957275,0.03333262407795885,0.03333604267834657]            |
|(20,[9,14,17],[0.4887254650789885,1.1856289804763125,1.3072768360965874])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |[0.03333373548732593,0.03333366047427678,0.0333388921917903,0.0333324500674453,0.03333165231618069,0.033333396263220766,0.03333392152736817,0.03333280784507405,0.03333341964532808,0.033332027450640234,0.03333590751407632,0.03333625709954709,0.033335027917460715,0.033332984179205334,0.0333395676850832,0.03333465555831355,0.03333317988602309,0.03332999573625669,0.033335686662720146,0.03333444862817325,0.033331118794333245,0.03333227594267816,0.03333337815403729,0.03332815318734183,0.03333329306551438,0.033332463398394074,0.03333211180252395,0.03332955750997137,0.03333267853415129,0.033331295475544864]              |
|(20,[0,1,2,5,6,8,9,12,14,19],[4.419484332447456,8.97780120222284,0.8914840021899768,1.3684833461617696,1.1252859305488734,1.233681992250468,0.4887254650789885,1.1654793679713804,42.68264329714725,3.685472474556911])                                                                                                                                                         |[0.03333847676223903,0.03333217319316553,0.03361190962478921,0.03322296565909072,0.033224152351515865,0.033305780550557426,0.0333623247307499,0.03333530792027193,0.03335048739584223,0.03328160880463601,0.0334726823486143,0.03350523767287266,0.0334249096308398,0.0333474750843313,0.033626678634369765,0.033399676341965154,0.033312708717161896,0.03316394279048787,0.033455734324711994,0.033388088146836026,0.03321934579333965,0.03331319196962562,0.03332496308901043,0.03308256004388311,0.033355283259340625,0.03328280644324275,0.0332436575330529,0.03319398288438216,0.03331402807784297,0.03320786022123095]                |
|(20,[2,8,10,13,15,16],[0.8914840021899768,3.701045976751404,1.6871692149804491,1.4594938792746623,0.8839314023462759,1.63668714555745])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |[0.0333356286958193,0.033332968808115676,0.03332196061288262,0.03333752852282297,0.03334171827141663,0.033333866506025614,0.03332902614535797,0.03332999721261129,0.03333228759033127,0.03333419089119785,0.033326295405433394,0.03332727748411373,0.03332970492260472,0.03333218324896459,0.033323419320752445,0.03333484772134479,0.033331408271507906,0.03333886892339302,0.033330223503670105,0.03333357612919576,0.033337166312023804,0.03333359583540509,0.033335058229509947,0.03334147190850166,0.03333378789809434,0.033336369234199595,0.033338417163238966,0.03333500103939193,0.03333456204893585,0.03333759214313734]          |
|(20,[0,1,5,9,11,14,18],[2.209742166223728,1.995066933827298,1.3684833461617696,0.4887254650789885,1.2395584596083011,1.1856289804763125,4.313137240759328])                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |[0.033331568372787335,0.03333199604802443,0.03333616626240888,0.03333311434679797,0.03332871558684149,0.03333377685027234,0.03333412369772984,0.03333326223955321,0.03333302350234804,0.033334011390192264,0.033332998734646985,0.03333572338531835,0.03333519102733107,0.033333669722909055,0.03333367298003543,0.03333316052548548,0.03333434503087792,0.03333204101430685,0.03333390212404242,0.03333317825522851,0.03333468470990933,0.0333342373715466,0.03333384912615554,0.03333262239313073,0.033332130871257,0.03333157173270879,0.033331620213171494,0.03333491236454045,0.03333364390007425,0.03333308622036798]                 |
|(20,[0,1,2,7,9,12,14,16,17],[1.104871083111864,1.995066933827298,1.7829680043799536,1.667281425641495,0.4887254650789885,3.4964381039141412,1.1856289804763125,1.63668714555745,1.3072768360965874])                                                                                                                                                                            |[0.033335136368759725,0.033335270064671074,0.033333243143688636,0.03333135191450168,0.03333521337181425,0.03333250351809707,0.03333535436589356,0.03333322757251989,0.033333747503130604,0.03333235416690325,0.03333273826809218,0.03333297626192852,0.033333297925505816,0.03333285267847805,0.033334741557111344,0.03333582976624498,0.03333192986853772,0.0333314389004771,0.03333186692894785,0.033332539165631093,0.03333280721245933,0.03333326073074502,0.03333359623114709,0.03333261337071022,0.03333404937430939,0.03333536871228382,0.033334559939835924,0.03333095099987788,0.0333326510660671,0.033332529051629894]            |
|(20,[2,5],[0.8914840021899768,1.3684833461617696])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |[0.033333008832987246,0.03333320773569408,0.03333212285409669,0.03333370183210235,0.03333408881228382,0.03333369017540667,0.03333315896362525,0.03333316321736793,0.033333273291611384,0.033332955144148683,0.03333299410668819,0.03333254807040678,0.03333302471306508,0.03333324003641127,0.033332032586187325,0.0333328866035473,0.033333366369446636,0.03333432146865401,0.033333080986559745,0.033332919796171534,0.03333365180032741,0.03333319727206391,0.0333336947744764,0.033334184463059975,0.033333428924387516,0.033333998899679654,0.033333803141837516,0.03333374053474702,0.03333339151988759,0.03333412307307108]          |
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you mean with mapping? By the way your termIndices doesn't look that good.

Comment: i want to get result as `Topic: 0
  more, blah, here, hey, words
Topic: 1
  foo, bar, blah, baz, boy` @cronoik

Comment: You mean you want map the termindices of each topic back to the actual terms?

Comment: Yes absolutely @cronoik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remap the terminindices to words you have to access the vocabulary of the [CountVectorizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel) model. Please have a look at the pseudocode below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#Reading your data...

cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="some", outputCol="features", vocabSize=2000)
cvmodel = cv.fit(df)
#other stuff

vocab = cvmodel.vocabulary
vocab_broadcast = sc.broadcast(vocab)

#creating LDA model
ldatopics = ldamodel.describeTopics()

def map_termID_to_Word(termIndices):
    words = []
    for termID in termIndices:
        words.append(vocab_broadcast.value[termID])

    return words

udf_map_termID_to_Word = udf(map_termID_to_Word , ArrayType(StringType()))

ldatopics_mapped = ldatopics.withColumn("topic_desc", udf_map_termID_to_Word(ldatopics.termIndices))
```